# Filter collection items

Tags: api-platform.com

I have a `manyToOne` relation (A has many B)

When I get A, I get a collection of `B`. All is ok at this point

But I have an "active" flag into B.

How can I only get active B items when I get A? Without using filters and manually exclude unwanted B items?

Comment: Simpelest is to add a getter like ::activeB and programmatically select the active items from the b relationship property. Or do you call that "manually"? Then i guess you can do this with [fetch join](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins) from a [Custom DataProvider](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/data-providers/#custom-collection-data-provider)

Comment: This isn't possible right now. See https://github.com/api-platform/core/issues/2253